# Printing grid-template-columns on more then one page (Angular - Angular Material)

Tags: html, css, angular

i am trying to print a div using
display:grid and grid-template-columns: 10em repeat(${this.nbDays} , 1fr) as properties of the div class.
This grid use grid-template-columns to repeat itself and  display as a table.
When i try to print the grid, using windows.print() the grid stay on the same page on the settings of the printer or pdf save option.
So i am not able to print the total size of my columns in my grid.

In the css if i use @meida print with a propertie of * { overflow: visible !important; }, i can see the pages on the printer settings, but the grid stay on one page.

I dont now how to use page-break-after on a grid with grid-template-columns.

```
 @media print {    
    * { overflow: visible !important; } 
    .noprint { 
      display: none !important; 
    }
    .calendar {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    @page {
      size: A3 landscape; 
   }
   .grid {
    width: inherit !important;
    min-width: inherit !important;
   }
   
  }

<div class="grid" [ngStyle]="{'grid-template-columns' : gridRepeat}">
    
            <mat-card *ngFor="xxx" class="stick days">
              <mat-card-content>
                <app-column-header>
                </app-column-header>
              </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
    
            <ng-container class="stick stick-horizontal"
              *ngFor="let xxx of xxx">
              <div class="stick-horizontal xxx">
                <span>{{ xxx }} <br> {{ xxx }}</span>
              </div>
              
              <ng-container *ngFor="let col of days" class="stick">
                <div>
                    <ng-container *ngFor="xxx">
                      <div></div>
                    </ng-container>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
          </div>

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```